# Flash - Stop webcam/mic access from being remembered

Tags: flash, webcam, microphone

I have an event that's triggered when the webcam/mic access is allowed/denied.

```
addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, sendStatusResponse);
```

I need sendStatusResponse to be fired everytime to let the server know the stream has started, however if the user has clicked on the remember checkbox this function is never fired.

Is there a way I can prevent them from clicking remember, or is there a better event to use so that I can store a timestamp of when the stream ACTUALLY started.

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the ACTIVITY event rather than STATUS:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#event:activity